# Exception: Failed to solve dependencies: 1:perl-JSON-XS-2.27-2.el6.x86_64 requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.10.1)

Tags: perl, installation, centos, plesk

Scenario: new installation of plesk 12.5 on centOS 7 into an OpenVZ container (proxmox):
Installing Plesk 12.5 I get the following error:
Exception: Failed to solve dependencies: 1:perl-JSON-XS-2.27-2.el6.x86_64 requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.10.1)

any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention CentOS 7, but the package you are attempting to install (perl-JSON-XS-2.27-2.el6.x86_64) is for RedHat/CentOS 6, denoted by the el6 tag in the package name.

In any case, the issue appears to be due to not having the correct repositories available in yum to solve all necessary dependencies.  Plesk maintains their own yum repositories to provide all of the necessary packages.  Usually the install script will handle this for you (the [install script](https://kb.plesk.com/en/119521) is just a quick way to obtain the Plesk autoinstaller which should have the proper source repository configured).

I would suggest you examine the currently configured yum repositories in your container and make sure there are no conflicting repositories.  Depending on the components you are installing with Plesk, it will want to manage nginx, apache, mysql, php, and some perl components so make sure you do not have yum repositories attempting to install related packages.  Also, if you are indeed using CentOS 7, make sure you have no repositories attempting to install CentOS 6 packages.  This bash one-liner should print out all the configured yum repository URLs so you can quickly scan if any are using the wrong version:

```
grep -re '^\(mirrorlist\|baseurl\)' /etc/yum.repos.d/
```

If you need further troubleshooting help, please include how you are attempting to install Plesk.